# Can I train new data with an old model using tensorflow?

Tags: audio, time, tensorflow, classification

I'm new to tensorflow and data science and i'm just trying to see if my idea is even possible.

I want to do simple sound detection with an HMM model in real time with tensorflow.

So I was thinking of saving a model in tensorflow and then somehow using that model to classify new new-incoming data.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You might need to work to feed things into the continually running systems but I think either queues or pulling the control flow outside of the graph should work for you.